# How Can I update embedded data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

oranization collection

```
{
 id:1,
 usergrp:[
    {grpname:"xyz",
     grpmembers:
      [{email:"abc",active:false},{email:"pqr",active:false}]
    },
    {grpname:"pqr",
     grpmembers:
      [{email:"def",active:false},{email:"ijk",active:false}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change active:true whose active:false and id=1
I want something like this

```
db.organizations.update(
  {"usergrp.grpmembers.email:false",id:1},
  {$set;{"usergrp.grpmembers.email":true}
})
```

How  I do this in mongodb

Comment: I'd suggest editing your post to format the code properly (and fix it - your first JSON object is not actually a legal object). It's all but illegible in its current state.

Comment: you are updating single mongo record. I don't see any problems with setting all "active" fields to true (including those already set)